# PHP store, retrieve and edit an array from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, pdo

I have a problem with arrays, I'm not so new in PHP but I have a little experience with manipulating complex arrays like one I need now.

I'm building shopping cart and my idea of cart is database row which every user will have and shopping process should go something like this

When user buys a product if product doesn't exist in the cart script should add product to the cart like e.g. `1=1` or in array words `$cart = [ [1]=>'1' ]` which means product ID1 quantity 1, now if product already exist in the cart script should just update quantity like e.g. `1=2` and so on for higher quantity.

This is my poor attempt to accomplish aforementioned

**PHP**

```
<?php session_start();

require_once('config.php');

$member_id = '1'; // Test data
$pr_id     = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pr_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); // Sending ID with jQuery/AJAX which works fine of course
$pr_qty    = '1'; // Start quantity
$up_qty    = '5'; // Test data

try {
  $getCart = $conn->prepare("SELECT cart FROM members WHERE member_id = :member_id ");
  $getCart->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id);
  $getCart->execute();
  $cart    = $getCart->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(array_key_exists($pr_id, $cart)) {
     $cart[$pr_id] = $up_qty . ',';
  }
  else {
     $cart[$pr_id] = $pr_qty . ',';
  }

  $updateCart = $conn->prepare("UPDATE members SET cart = :cart WHERE member_id = :member_id ");
  $updateCart->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id);
  $updateCart->bindParam(':cart', implode($cart));

  if($updateCart->execute()) {
     echo '1';
  }

}
catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $error->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Later on I should be able to retrieve product ID's and quantities from database but when the time comes...

I'm working about three days on this and I'm hopeless, I searched everywhere, find many tutorials on multidimensional arrays but I think that my problem is a little unique or I'm just stupid enough and can't solve it.

Thanks everyone in advance, I hope we'll solve it together, more brains = more knowledge = solution ;)

Comment: What shows `var_dump($cart)`?

Comment: is `$conn` a mysqli object or a pdo object?

Comment: @u_mulder It shows `NULL` but when I echo it with implode it shows `1,1,1,`

Comment: Within your first `try` you've used variables within your prepare statement. Prepared statements (or at least in mySQLi::prepare) do not allow variable injection this way to prevent SQL injection so I believe. try using bindParam to add your variables to the statement.

Comment: @Beneto in the first statement I'm pulling cart from database and it works ok when I echo it with `implode` it shows data in the cart but `array_key_exists` doesn't work.

Comment: @mdesdev Yes sorry I've literally just read pdo::prepare. Says it doesn't prevent variable injection the way you've used it. Wouldn't that be because the data from the database is a String and not an array? How it it structure in the database? With commas or?

Comment: @Beneto yes cart row data is comma delimited.

Comment: @mdesdev `implode($cart + $upCart)` can you explain what are you doing here

Comment: @meda `implode($cart + $upCart)` store initial cart in database + adds new product in cart because product with the same id has not been found in the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [implode](http://www.php.net/implode) function you use will not work for your cart, because the array indices get lost, so you lose the product IDs. But you can [serialize](http://www.php.net/serialize) or [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) your shopping cart array.

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
    1 => 1,
    6581 => 4
);

$json = json_encode($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Then you can store the `$json` string to your member table. When you want to fetch it from the database later, you have to [json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode) it and put the function result in `$_SESSION['cart']` again.

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = json_decode($json, true);
```

As you see, I have put your `$cart` variable into the `$_SESSION`. Thus you do not need to retrieve it again from the database when the user navigates on your site. This will  reduce load on the database as well as speed up your script. For a shopping website it is really important that the website will load as fast as possible, so that the customers enjoy shopping and staying on the site.

To add a new product or to increase the quantity of an existing position simply do this:

```
function addProduct($id)
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]++;
    else
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = 1;
}
```

After calling addProduct you should [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) and update the database to make the cart persistent.

Comment: Ok but I need to edit/update array and show data based on cart id's.

Comment: I'll take a better look at this.

Comment: Sorry doesn't help...I need to store, retrieve, edit and store again, storing isn't much problem as edit in place and storing again.

Comment: That is pretty easy. Keep the `$cart` array in the session. When you alter something, simply do an update query. Use `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` instead of `$cart = array();`. Then you can work with your cart without the need to retrieve it again and again. When making a change to it, just do a `json_encode` and do an update.

Comment: I dont use `$cart = array();` I'm pulling cart from database row so when user close the browser, go and come again the cart is intact. That's my problem with `$_SESSION['cart']`. I could put cart in session variable but I must pull cart data from database so session doesn't help much in my case. If you could provide an example for my exact situation with store, retrieve, edit...that would be helpfull.

Comment: Why is it not possible for you to use the session? When the user closes his browser and comes back later you could query the cart from database and store it in the session again.

Comment: Ok, that's true, but again my biggest problem is editing and storing back again and I'm a little bit stuck about it...

Comment: Have you taken a look at the addProduct() function?

Comment: Ok, after whole day of searching I've decided to use `json_encode();` & `json_decode()` except I don't using session cart, instead I'm using cart as single row and encoding when update, decoding when retrieve. In the end I succeeded somehow, thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, one way to implement this would be by having multiple database rows per cart, instead of encoding all the data into one. I would propose a database structure a little bit like this:

[image: Database Diagram]

This completely separates everything, so that editing and expanding is a lot simpler. For example, this way would make it really easy to allow users to have multiple carts, like Amazon does!

This simplifies the code a hell of a lot!

I won't write out the code for you, because I don't have the time, but I'll explain how it works a little bit, so you can have a go yourself!

### To retrieve a cart:

You can get any carts belonging to a user by:

- Getting the user id
- Searching for a cart_id from the Cart table with that user id. If each user only has one, select the first one.
- Select all the rows from the Cart_items table with that cart_id. This will give you each individual product in that cart
- To get information on each product, select that products row from the Products table, using it's PID.

### To add an item:

- Get the cart ID as above
- check if a row exists with both the ID of the product and ID of the cart
- If there is, increase the quantity (see below)
- If there isn't, create the row.

### To edit items:

- Get the cart id as above.
- Get the Product id of the product you want to edit
- Update that row of Cart_items with those 2 IDs to change the quantity etc.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for such elaborate answer but it doesn't help me. Proposing a totally new db structure isn't good answer. I'm creating a simple shopping cart and don't want to complicate things with so many db tables just one cart row per user with simple `ID=QTY` product entry. Anyway that's my idea of cart structure for this project.